# Optimize code for adding class to selected items across multiple sections, individually

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, optimization

I'm creating a form with multiple choice and single choice questions. Whenever an user clicks on an option, it gets the class `.checked`.

**For single option**

```
$(function() {
    $('#device li').click(function() {
        $('#device li.checked').removeclass('checked');
        $(this).addClass('checked');
    });
});
```

**For multiple choice**

```
$(function() {
    $('#targetAudience li').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
            $(this).removeClass('checked');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('checked');
        }
    });
});
```

However, for each question, I have to copy-paste the adequate piece of code and change the `ID` within. The problem is that is completely inefficient. Therefor I would like to optimize the code for a more general, all-over code piece.

The DOM-structure looks like this

```
<ul id="buildForm"> // Complete form
    <li id="FillInSubjectHere" class="question"> // question container
        <h3></h3> //Question title
        <ul> // Answer array container
            <li class="option"> // checkable answer     
            <li class="option"> // checkable answer     
        </ul>       
    </li>
</ul>
```

The goal of this: 
At this point, I have to write a piece of code for each question each, otherwise they'd interfere with each other. However, I want two (1 for multiple choice, 1 for single-choice) (Bonus if you can do it with one) pieces of code that specifies all questions within the `#buildForm`, without having to specify each question each. This to prevent having to alter the Javascript when adding a new question.

The code has to function so when a user clicks a single-option question option, the option gets `.checked` and all other options within **this** question don't. With multiple-choice question, the `.checked` gets added when they don't have this class yet. Else, it will be removed removed.

Comment if you need more info. Thanks very much!

Comment: A side note: you'll like `.toggleClass()`

Comment: Hmm, smart. Well, that's one step already. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single answer:

```
$(function() {
    $('.question.singleanswer .option').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('clicked').siblings().removeClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

For multiple answers:

```
$(function() {
    $('.question.multipleanswers .option').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

You can combine this two functions if you like.

Comment: After reviewing your code.. This seemed much easier than expected. Incredibly thanks, mate!